# How to display array value in Django template?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I have the following array and would like to display day name in the template.

```
DAYS = ((0, "Saturday"),
        (1, "Sunday"),
        (2, "Monday"),
        (3, "Tuesday"),
        (4, "Wednesday"))
```

I can display Monday by using `{{ DAYS.2.1 }}` but I was unable to display using `{{DAYS.class_weekday.key_value.1}}`.

I am getting `class_weekday.key_value` from a for loop but when I use `class_weekday.key_value` there then it's not showing anything!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
{{ instance.get_day_display }}
```

in your templates. That select the display value instead of the database value.

If you want to display all the values :

```
[ x for x, y in DAYS ]
```

will return a list containing the list of days,

Comment: Thanks! I am not using for loop in the template. The DAYS array is available in the template but I want to just display the value based on the key i.e. {{ DAYS[2] }} for Monday.

Comment: do you know how to use weekday.key_value from a for loop i.e. {{DAYS.weekday.key_value.1}} to display the day name? When I use weekday.key_value there then it's not showing anything! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As per django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups

***Variables and lookups***

Variable names must consist of any letter (A-Z), any digit (0-9), an underscore (but they must not start with an underscore) or a dot.

Dots have a special meaning in template rendering. A dot in a variable name signifies a lookup. Specifically, when the template system encounters a dot in a variable name, it tries the following lookups, in this order:

```
Dictionary lookup. Example: foo["bar"]
Attribute lookup. Example: foo.bar
List-index lookup. Example: foo[bar]
```

**Note that “bar” in a template expression like {{ foo.bar }} will be interpreted as a literal string and not using the value of the variable “bar”, if one exists in the template context.**

So you can use custom filter for this purpose.

You can make custom template filter:

```
#here, import DAYS
@register.filter
def return_day(i):
    try:
        return DAYS[i][1]
    except:
        return N.A
```

And in template

```
{{ class_weekday.key_value|return_day }}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you want is `DAYS[2][1]` :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21425318)

Comment: this clairly respond to the question @stovfl, he just want to display 'Monday', for now he print only a tuple, et need the extra [1], someone else posted the same on a comment and that was the answer...